# Is it possible to use DateTime.Now through a loop, that only inputs the current time after the loop finished?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm currently making a system that converts an excel-sheet into an xml-file using a foreach loop. One of the daterows is a timestamp, which is supposed to be the time generated when the program has finished.

I realize i can have the time when the program starts by defining the time variable before the loop. However each row needs a timestamp, and the program takes 30 seconds to about a 2 minutes to run based on excel-size

I can also have the timestamp inside the foreach loop, where the last timestamp would be correct, and the remaining would get closer to correct the further into the sheet we get.

But can i somehow define the time as the absolute last thing the program does before it finishes?

Simplified my code for everything relevant:

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    

foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("trades");
    writer.WriteElementString("time", time);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

So i want all my xml elements to show the current time when the program finished

Comment: You could read all the data into memory, then set a timestamp to use before writing it out (if the amount of data isn't too large), but no matter what some amount of time will pass from when you get the current time to when it actually writes the data to the file.

Comment: Why do you want to have the time in each row if it will have the exact same tamestamp ? Maybe if you just only write the timestamp on the last row if will be like the very last instruction :)

Comment: Consider redefining either your expectations or the rest of the system so that it isn't actually an issue. Anything that relies on a shared timestamp between a lot of rows, where the timestamp is supposed to be *after* the process finished, is a bit suspect.

Comment: I'd suggest to write a placeholder to the time column, then use another iteration over the file to find and replace the placeholder. You can do that easily in bash.

Answer (score 1):

Hack, but does literally what you ask (I agree with concerns raised by commentors - note this is an implementation of Mugen's answer).

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Skip(1))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("trades");
    writer.WriteElementString("time", "%%__TIME__%%");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}

string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");    

string xml = // here serialize the xml from writer

IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,xml.Replace("%%__TIME__%%",time);
```

Cons:

- has to hold xml in memory
- can't have the template string in the data
- Will be a delay while the file is written

Comment: Thanks, I agree with the concerns aswell, but due to my situation i suddenly started wondering if such a thing would actually be possible. However like other people suggested, i'll likely see if can find a completely alternative way of doing it :) But thanks a lot!